# I cannot stop an ajax request using jQuery and abort() function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, abort

My jQuery is below:

```
var x = $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=google&v=1.0",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Jsonp data: " + msg );
    }
});

alert(x);  // x is undefined
// x.abort()​​
```

​

You can try this code here: http://jsbin.com/iyile3/2/edit

I want stop this ajax request and stop this ajax request's success function.

But what I get is that "x" is undefined , I think I doesn't stop this ajax request and its success function.

So can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

Well that makes sense.

A `jsonp` call is not an ordinary `XMLHttpRequest` (which .ajax() normally returns). It would not work that way since you cannot break out the `same origin policy`.

JSON-Padding works with dynamic script tag insertion. So basically, jQuery just creates a `<script>` tag on your site and loads the data over that. No `XHR` object at all.

I don't think there is a way to early abort that kind of request, but I hope someone will correct me here if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yep. There's no way to kill an Jsonp request using abort() function.

But I think I've fixed this problem using JavaScript serTimeout() function. Perhaps someone would also uses clearTimeout() function. That's good. But in my this case, I only use setTimeout function to fix out the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) may be a little misleading on this one. No AJAX request is made when using JSONP. In this case, the `ajax` function returns an `undefined` value instead of the object of `XMLHTTPRequest`.